# indexOf in Javascript not working how it should

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the page number out if these possible strings:

`$scope.projects.next` can equal...

- string 1) /api/project/?currentuser=false&page=2
- string 2)
  /api/project/?page=2

I have tried this:

```
$scope.projects.next.split('=')[1].indexOf("page")
```

However, this only works on string 2. How can I change this to make sure it finds the page number no matter what position or future arguments that could be added?

I have also tried:

```
$scope.projects.next.indexOf("page")
```

but this gives `52` no idea why.

Comment: because `indexOf` returns the starting character index in the string that the passed argument starts at

Comment: Why split at all? just find index of `page=` and there it is.

Comment: `split('page=')` will probably work, but you'll still have a problem if that param/value pair don't come at the end of your string. You're probably better off using a regex to find the `\d+` after 'page=`

Comment: @Shiju K Babu its a string that represents a URL.

Comment: @Spike Is that a URL? Then you can use `$routeParams` if that's just a String value only, you need to use RegEx or something.

Comment: The indexOf function returns the position of the data specified in the parentheses. For example "hello".indexOf('e') will return 1 since "e" occurs at the second position of the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
/page=([0-9]+)/.exec($scope.projects.next)[1]
```

That uses a regular expression with a capture group (the bit in `()`) for the page number, and captures one or more digits after `page=`. The result is an array, where the first element is the *whole* match, and the second is the capture group (that's why we have `[1]` at the end).

Comment: +1 - It's always best to *explain* what you've done as well as showing the code for doing it. I've added that bit, but it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: ok this works well, tested it with a few different arguments and always seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

please see here: http://jsbin.com/gizalo/1/edit

function to get parametr from string

```
function getParameterByName(name, string) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(string);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

 var stringa="/api/project/?currentuser=false&page=2";
 var stringb="/api/project/?page=2";

 $scope.a = getParameterByName('page', stringa);
 $scope.b = getParameterByName('page', stringb);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the first url there are two = signs so your index would be out by 1 on the first url

$scope.projects.next.split('page=')[1]

Comment: This seems to work for my case. How does this stand up with adding new arguments to the string?

Answer (score 0):

This has absolutely nothing to do with AngularJS. But it's also simple, so why not answer. Splitting on a character splits on EVERY instance of that character. Your top string is going to end up being `['/api/project/?currentuser', 'false&page', '2']`, so getting the position of `[1]('page')` isn't useful. Split it on `?` instead.

Comment: you would then need to split again on & and then on =

Comment: Split on ? then take the 2nd element of the resulting array and split on & and then loop through the array until you find a string that contains 'page=' and split on = and then take the 2nd element of that array

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = $scope.projects.next.indexOf("page=");
var end   = $scope.projects.next.indexOf("&");

var page;

if(end == -1) {
    page = $scope.projects.next.substring(start+5);
} else {
    page = $scope.projects.next.substring(start+5, end);
}
```

This would also work for ?page=17&test=2